# How resize image and create thumbnail in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have function to upload images in codeigniter, here i can upload any images, but when i need to show this images in my site i will use this code :-

```
<img src="uploads/<?=$user->pic?>" width="250px" height="200px" />
```

if the image max than 250, the image not show good.

So how can i do thumb for my pic.

```
public function do_upload($field) {
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field)) 
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        return $error;
    } 
    else
    {
      $updata =$this->upload->data();
      $data = $updata['raw_name'].$updata['file_ext'];
      return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go, just specify file_path and thats it (+width/height)
for more options take a look in [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html)

```
public function resize_image($file_path, $width, $height) {

    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $img_cfg['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $img_cfg['source_image'] = $file_path;
    $img_cfg['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $img_cfg['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $img_cfg['new_image'] = $file_path;
    $img_cfg['width'] = $width;
    $img_cfg['quality'] = 100;
    $img_cfg['height'] = $height;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($img_cfg);
    $this->image_lib->resize();

}
```

Comment: does it create a file? filename should be same as uploaded file + _thumb.extenstion

Comment: yes create and the thumb not at 200px width - and 200px height why